# Netty one thread per channel limitation when implementing a protocol stack

Tags: stack, protocols, netty

I want to implement a protocol stack with netty

on the low level there is only one long lasting channel connecting the client and the server
but at one layer above, this channel is used by multiple clients.

Is there a way to open a new channel object in Netty that will deal with each client of the upper layer in an elegant manner ?

Looking forward to hearing form you guys

Answer (score 0):

Netty not know about your layer on top and just provide you with the Channel. You can use this Channel from multiple threads but how you do use it is up to you.